# Влияние url на идексацию

Tags: url, seo, индексация

Какой url лучше для .ru сайтов в плане индексации?

```
somesite.domen/news/policy/
somesite.domen/novosti/politika/
somesite.domen/новости/политика/
```

Хотелось бы получить ответ, раскрывающий тему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `SEO` плане первый вариант будет предпочтительнее, т.к поисковики обычно ориентируются на наличие некоторых ключевых слов в `url` *(в вашем случае, **news**).*

Тем не менее, если душа тяготеет к третьему варианту, то возможно использовать и его, поскольку ключевые слова **новости** и **политика** будут предположительно распознаны с таким же успехом.

*Второй же вариант - это вообще ни рыба, ни мясо, да и, честно говоря, составлять `url'ы` из слов, набранных транслитом - это моветон.*

---

Да, кстати говоря, корректным переводом здесь будет `politics`, а не `policy`, поскольку `policy`, конечно, переводится в словарях как `политика`, но на деле обозначает *некоторую стратегию*, а не *политику* в плане публичной жизни государства и властей.

Answer (score 0):

Тот или иной URL будет однозначно проиндексирован, любой вариант имеет право на существование. Среди СЕОшников достаточно много людей абсолютно равнодушных к виду URL. Сам URL никак не относится к тому что чем он красивее, тем сайт лучше индексируется.

Answer (score 0):

Я обращался с подобными вопросами и в гугл и в яндекс, ответ был один и тот-же.

Дословно и коротко:

Нам пофигу ваш урл, следите чтобы после его ввода страница была интереснои без плагиата бла бла бла